# Comparing dates in sas

Tags: sas

I am using proc sql on a data set and only want to include values where the date is before 2003. The dates in the dataset are in the format of DDMMMYYYY - for ex. 01JAN2004.

I'm trying to use:

```
proc sql;
select Name, Department, Join_Date format = WORDDATE.w.
from xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
where Join_Date < 01JAN2003;

quit;
```

But this does not work

Answer (score 1):

Your date value isn't being recognised as such.  Try:

```
proc sql;
select Name, Department, Join_Date format = WORDDATE.w.
from xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
where Join_Date < '01JAN2003'd;

quit;
```

Comment: Thank you! It's the simplest things that get me.